# Fabric initialization could not calculate hash for app icon in case of Android Instant Apps

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, android-instant-apps

I am initializing Fabric in Application class as

```
Fabric.with(context, crashlyticsKit);
```

My project is divided into three modules - base feature module, apk-wrapper module and an instant-app module. App Icon is declared as `application` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml` of base feature module.

At startup of Instant app, Fabric throws following error

```
E/Fabric: Could not calculate hash for app icon.
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1265)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1241)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.getAppIconHashOrNull(CommonUtils.java:824)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.initialize(Settings.java:83)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:124)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you’ve already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606527/twitter-no-package-identifier-when-getting-value-for-resource-number-0x00000000.  Double check your setup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361850/how-do-i-integrate-crashlytics-with-android-instant-apps and make sure you are on the latest version 2.6.8 https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Fabric + Instant Apps. It's not critical though and will only mean your console will not be able to display your app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the app icons and make sure your app has the proper launcher icon for all versions (both **android:icon** and **android:roundIcon** )

Make sure to have a proper fallback to versions below 26 if you use adaptive icons.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an app icon in your `manifest` like so:

```js
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" <----- add this
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
        ...
        ...
</application>
```